# How to put a big matrix in an a4 page

Tags: matrices

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{geometry}
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
    (rp+(s+p-1)+qp-(q+p-1)+t-1)& -(pr-r-t+1) & -(pq-s-t+1)& 0& -(q-1)&0\\
    \hline
    -(qs-r-tr+1)& (fr-(r+q-1)+pq-mq+p-1)+(t-1))& -(pq-p-q+1)& -(q-1)& 0& 0\\
    \hline
    -(qsr-r-q+1)& -(ur-r-p+1)&(pr-(h+p-1)+qr-(g+q-1)+r-1) & 0& 0& -(r-1)\\
    \hline
    0& -(pr-r-p+1) & 0 &(mr-r-p+1) & 0& 0\\
    \hline
    -(qs-r-q+1)& 0&0 &0 & (qn-r-q+1) & 0\\
    \hline
    0& 0& -(pq-s-q+1)& 0& 0& (hq-q-p+1)\\
    \end{array}
\right)

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Given the following matrix code, I find that it is very difficult to put the matrix in a4 paper.
The whole matrix is not fitting in my page.
Is there any way I can put the whole matrix in my page and even see it properly

What are some ways to put a big matrix in a page?

Comment: What's the purpose of the 5 `\hline` directives?

Comment: @Mico;  i tried to fit the matrix after removing the $\hline$ but its still the same

Comment: please make your example complete, it can not be run as you have posted it, and we could guess a documentclass, but that sets the page size so affects the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment instead of an `array` environment, to allow automatic line breaking. The example given below shows how to center all cells both horizontally and vertically and place them into math mode automatically.

I would also load the `booktabs` package and replace all `\hline` directives with `\addlinespace`, for a more open "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%% New:
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env.
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % center cell contents *vertically*
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering$}X<{$}} % centered 'X' col. type & auto math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
    rp+(s+p-1)+qp-(q+p-1)+t-1 & -(pr-r-t+1) & -(pq-s-t+1)& 0 & -(q-1) & 0\\
    \addlinespace
    -(qs-r-tr+1) & (fr-(r+q-1)+pq-mq+p-1)+(t-1)) & -(pq-p-q+1) & -(q-1) & 0 & 0\\
    \addlinespace
    -(qsr-r-q+1) & -(ur-r-p+1) & pr-(h+p-1)+qr-(g+q-1)+r-1 & 0 & 0 & -(r-1) \\
    \addlinespace
    0 & -(pr-r-p+1) & 0 & mr-r-p+1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \addlinespace
    -(qs-r-q+1)& 0 & 0 & 0 & qn-r-q+1 & 0 \\
    \addlinespace
    0 & 0 & -(pq-s-q+1) & 0 & 0 & hq-q-p+1\\
\end{tabularx}\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are just awesome!! I have been struggling with this and you just fixed it so easily , one of the masters of TeX stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

I  propose to use a  medium-size matrix (`mmatrix` from `nccmath`, about 80% of display style), reduce a bit the value of `\arraycolsize`, use the aligned environment for the three very long expressions and decrease locally the margins with the `adjustwidth` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
 \usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
\left(
\begin{mmatrix}
    \begin{aligned}\bigl(rp +(s&+p-1)\\[-0.8ex] {}+qp -(q&+p-1)\\[-0.8ex] & +t-1\bigr)\end{aligned}& -(pr-r-t+1) & -(pq-s-t+1)& 0& -(q-1)&0\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
    -(qs-r-tr+1)& \begin{aligned}\bigl(fr -(r&+q-1)\\[-0.8ex] {}+pq -mq& +p-1)\\[-0.8ex] & +(t-1)\bigr)\end{aligned}& -(pq-p-q+1)& -(q-1)& 0& 0\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
    -(qsr-r-q+1)& -(ur-r-p+1)& \begin{aligned}\bigl(pr -(h&+p-1)\\[-0.8ex]{}+qr -(g&+q-1)\\[-0.8ex] & +r-1\bigr)\end{aligned} & 0& 0& -(r-1)\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
    0& -(pr-r-p+1) & 0 &(mr-r-p+1) & 0& 0\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
    -(qs-r-q+1)& 0&0 &0 & (qn-r-q+1) & 0\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-6}
    0& 0& -(pq-s-q+1)& 0& 0& (hq-q-p+1)\\
    \end{mmatrix}
\right)
\end{equation}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, sorry I cant accept it as I have already used the solution givenby@Mico